# sending activity as argument to the custom adapter of a listview and then sending it to a popup menu class too and then intent the same activity

Tags: android, listview, popup, adapter

I have a Listview with several members and each member is composed of 5 items

One of these 5 items is an Imageview called "delete_item" which is there to delete the member it belongs to (if user long clicks on it)

When the user long clicks on "delete_item", I open a popup menu composed of 2 items so that the user select one of them:
1 - trash Imageview
2 - return Imageview

If the the user clicks on trash Imageview then that member is deleted and if the user clicks on the return item, nothing would happen but dismissing the dialog as following:

`popupWindow.dismiss();`

I have to pass Activity from Listview adapter to the popup class for inflation too:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myActivity.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Everything works fine but there are 2 questions as following:

Question 1 - Is it a true action to send Activity as argument firstly to the custom adapter of the Listview and then for the second time to the popup class called from that adapter ?

Question 2 - When the user clickes on trash Imageview and I delete the member, I re-intent the activity which the popup menu comes from, Is it a true action to intent the same activity which we are in ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the `LayoutInflater` through any context.

You can get context from any View. Like,

```
Context ctx=view.getContext();
LayoutInflater inflater= ((AppCompatActivity)ctx).getLayoutInflater();
```

alternatively, if you have any Container object, then simply get it by: `container.getLayoutInflater();`

Comment: So you mean sending Activity is not true ? can you explain why?

Comment: BTW, what about sending Activity to custom adapter?

Comment: Sending Activity to Adapter is not a good practice. The code should be less coupled.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Insane Developer the answer for your second question:

You should have a method called notifiyDataSetChanged() in your adapter to redraw your ListView. It is a lot better than restarting the activity.

Comment: The point is popup menu is a new class and is not in the adapter so it's not possible to do as you say, isn't it?

Comment: If you're creating the popup inside the adapter you could create an interface that is implemented by the adapter and then just send the adapter to the popup as the mentioned interface.

Comment: Set click listener and get a callback in the activity and show a popup from the callback method.

Comment: Can you provide me with a simple example? BTW, The pop up has to be close to the delete_item which is clicked too